# Failed to resolve module specifier "express". I am getting this error in my browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have imported express in my code but it gives me this error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "express". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Can somebody help me with this. Thanks.

This is my main.js

```js
import express from 'express';

import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const { clientID, clientSecret, port } = require('./config.json');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', async ({ query }, response) => {
    const { code } = query;

    if (code) {
        try {
            const oauthResult = await fetch('https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token', {
                method  : 'POST',
                body    : new URLSearchParams({
                    client_id     : clientID,
                    client_secret : clientSecret,
                    code,
                    grant_type    : 'authorization_code',
                    redirect_uri  : `http://localhost:${port}`,
                    scope         : 'identify'
                }),
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            });

            const oauthData = await oauthResult.json();

            const userResult = await fetch('https://discord.com/api/users/@me', {
                headers : {
                    authorization : `${oauthData.token_type} ${oauthData.access_token}`
                }
            });

            console.log(await userResult.json());
        } catch (error) {
            // NOTE: An unauthorized token will not throw an error;
            // it will return a 401 Unauthorized response in the try block above
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

    return response.sendFile('index.html', { root: '.' });
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening at http://localhost:${port}`));
```

And this my start.js:

```js
// file start.js
require = require('esm')(module /*, options*/);
module.exports = require('./main.js');
```

Comment: Did you run npm install express?

Comment: Yes, I have installed it.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://medium.com/threejs/module-specifiers-versus-relative-import-references-fd747980ba6f)?

Answer (score 0):

[remove the express import from the current file you are writting code to remove Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "express". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ucmi.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code.